# Centos NTP time skew alerts

Tags: centos, centos7, ntp, time, time-synchronization

I have a couple of NTP Stratum 2 servers, and these are in sync with a Stratum 1 GPS appliance, and also peered between them selves. I would be interested in creating a job, which will create an alert if the time difference between Stratum 1 and Stratum 2 goes off by X seconds etc.
I appreciate any help on this..

Thanks

Comment: What host monitoring system are you using? Good ones can be extended with plugins, which could be used to check the offset.

Comment: Hi John, I only have scom monitoring.. We are still to implement Zabbix etc..Is there any script that i can run locally on the CentOS server ?